# Shortcode with hyphen doesn't work

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to do a simple basic shortcode and it fails.  I have boiled it down to the most simple test and it still fails.

Here is the code:

```
/** My test shortcode */
function bp_basic_shortcode() {
return "This is a shortcode doing this!";
}
add_shortcode( 'basic_shortcode', 'bp_basic_shortcode');
```

In trying to figure out what is the reason I have:

I have put this in the functions.php file of the stock template twentytwelve

I have deactivated all plugins

I have added the shortcode [basic-shortcode] in both a post and a page as a test with the same result.

I used the "text" tab of the editor to add the shortcode

I see just the text of [basic-shortcode] but it is not being processed.

I even installed a plugin to show all active shortcodes and it is indeed in the list.

I have tried it both on an instance of my MAMP server and one on my VPS

This should be really simple.  What am I missing??

Answer (score 4):

You registered the shortcode `basic_shortcode`, but you tested the wrong `[basic-shortcode]`. These are two different things.

Comment: Not trying to argue - honestly.

I assure you I used the underscores initially in the [basic_shorcode] tag I placed in the page under the text tab.

When I changed them in the action declaration and the page to "-" the shortcake worked both locally and on the server.

Comment: @toscho https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens doesn't say anything about "invalid", it just points out some side effect risks. I've been using hyphenized shortcodes without any issues for years.

Comment: @lkraav True, I remember some problems, but it doesn't look like an issue anymore. Updated my answer. :)

Answer (score -2):

Silly spell check on the MAC  - It's "shortcodes" not "shortcakes"

But to answer the question - this is SO trivial stupid and I had not seen this mentioned anywhere:  You MAY NOT use an underscore in the shortcode tag.

Maybe this will help someone else.  I sure hope so.

Comment: That's not true. Underscores are fine, hyphens are not.

Comment: I thought they should be but in WP 4.8.1 they fail as tested in my MAMP and online server.  I changed them to "-"s and all is well.

Crazy huh?  Maybe a bug introduced in this version?

Comment: @toscho  Can you confirm if this is true in 4.8.1 or not in your own testing?